# AngularJS Trigger $scope.broadcast from $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

### Introduction

I am trying to make sure that I am using all the parts of my angular application correctly / all the right code is in the right place.

I came across this article 
http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/
which has an example application with data stored in an array inside a service. I feel like the way the app is structured makes sense (but could be completely wrong).

### The Question

Can I trigger a $broadcast to happen when a $resource action fires in the same way that I trigger a $broadcast when the array is updated in this code.

```
myApp.service( 'Book', function( $rootScope ) {

var service = {

    books: [
      { title: "Magician", author: "Raymond E. Feist" },
      { title: "The Hobbit", author: "J.R.R Tolkien" }
    ],
    addBook: function ( book ) {
        service.books.push( book );
        //console.log(service.books);
        $rootScope.$broadcast( 'books.update' );
    }
}

return service;

});
```

Here is a plunker of a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/y56oQvrvK6OgXJEPJSv7?p=previewin

### Bonus Question

If I **can** do what I'm asking then the other question is **should** I? I see the alternative as having **all** the interactions with service (and the $resource in it) take place in the controller (which is what I have done until now)

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you're asking. A `$resource` will return an object/array that has a `$promise` property. You can use this promise to know when the server request succeeds/fails.

In the success/fail handler, you do `$rootScope.$broadcast()` as needed. Here's a service that uses the `query()` method of a `$resource` to do this:

**EDIT**

Here is the full service implementation. Note you can skin this cat many ways, so these are just some example ideas.

```
myApp.service( 'Book', function($rootScope, $resource ) {

var myResource = $resource('/books/:id', { id: '@id' } );
var books;    
var service = {   
    // this function broadcasts the result
    getBooks: function() {
        myResource.query(
            function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('it.worked', response);
            },
            function(error) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('it.failed', error);
            }
        );
    },
    // this function returns the $resource and also keeps a copy
    // so someone else may get the data with getBooksResult()
    getBooks2: function() {
        books = myResource.query();
        books.$promise(
            function(response) {
                // if you still need to broadcast...
                $rootScope.$broadcast('it.worked');
            },
            function(error) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('it.failed');
            }
        );
        return books;
    },
    getBookResult: function() {
        return books;
    }
}

return service;
});
```

**Should you do this?**

I don't see a lot of harm in doing this, but you should at least give it some thought. You are going to `$broadcast()` an event from the top of your application's scope hierarchy down to every other scope in your app.

This will likely send the event to scopes that don't care at all about the event. Keep in mind that there are could be many scopes in your app (created by controllers/directives). Probably not a big deal in most cases.

The nice thing about `$resource` is that it returns you an empty object, that is later filled in with the server response. So often times you don't need resort to broadcasting the result :) Views that use the resource's return value will update automagically. And controller's that need the value (or error) can use the `$promise` from the `$resource` as I've shown above.

Comment: Hi Mate,
Thanks very much for the quick and detailed reply. Your example wasn't _exactly_ what I was asking (I was talking about broadcasting from inside the service not from the controller or the directive) but your remarks on the consequences of $broadcast make me think this isn't the best solution.

When you say "Views that use the resource's return value will update automagically" how does that apply if I am accessing the same $resource service from two controllers? If i update the $resource from one controller the view for the other controller doesn't seem to update?

Comment: @PaulParton My example was just the "body" of a service. I was too lazy to write the full service. Imagine your original service, but you also inject the `$rootScope` into the service. Let me edit... The problem you describe (w/the second controller) is exactly why you should put this code in a service...

Comment: @PaulParton updated my answer. Keep in mind I don't know your exact use case, so this code is a bit contrived. The solution for your two controllers problem lies in a service that does something similar to the above. Another idea is to use the caching functionality of `$http` (and therefore `$resource`). You can cache the data via `$http` and let your controllers query away. Later you can empty the cache so the next query will hit the server.

Comment: Aaahh I see where you are coming from now, thank you very much for taking the time to add all that extra detail. Thanks for the tip about http caching too, that looks good.